# Lou multi-select filter DUAL List by optgroup Label

Tags: javascript

i'm using bootstrap multi select from http://loudev.com/ ... none of the similar questions involve dual lists and pure JS. I need to be able to filter a search by optgroup. When I search for the optgroup label the search results (children of group) disappears.

Note ** I use different list options in the example images.. but the outcome should be same.

I've tried to program where the optgroup label and its children are visible.

js fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ksweat/13sn45xL/23/

List before filtering: 
[image: List before filtering]

List after filters:
[image: List after filters]

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="searchableb" name="my-select[]">      
  <optgroup label='Friends'>
    <option value='1'>Yoda</option>
    <option value='2' selected>Obiwan</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label='Enemies'>
    <option value='3'>Palpatine</option>
    <option value='4' disabled>Darth Vader</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>


$('.searchableb').multiSelect({
  selectableHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>All References</div><input type='text' class='search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder=' Search '>",
  selectionHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Assigned</div><input type='text' class='search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder=' Search '>",
  enableClickableOptGroups: true,
  enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  afterInit: function (ms) {
    var that = this,
      $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
      $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
      selectableSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
      selectionSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';


    that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString,{
      'show': function () {

        $(this).prev(".ms-optgroup-label").show();
        $(this).show();
      },
      'hide': function () {
        $(this).prev(".ms-optgroup-label").hide();
        $(this).hide();
      }
    })
      .on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.which === 40){
          that.$selectableUl.focus();
          return false;
        }
      });

    that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
      .on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 40) {
          that.$selectionUl.focus();
          return false;
        }
      });
  },
  afterSelect: function (values) {
    let url = $('#typeEdit').val();
    // get removed emps
    let removedRefs = $('.removedRefs').val();
    removedRefs = removedRefs.split(',');
    console.log('values', values)
    let listid = values[0].split("- / -");

    // if an employee is reselected, find in string and remove
    var index = removedRefs.indexOf(listid[0]);
    if (index > -1) {
      removedRefs.splice(index, 1);
    }
    removedRefs = removedRefs.toString();
    console.log(removedRefs);
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  },

  afterDeselect: function (values) {
    let url = $('#typeEdit').val();
    let action = false;
    let removedRefs = $('.removedRefs').val();
    let listid = values[0].split("- / -");
    console.log(listid[0])
    vals.push(listid[0]);
    $('.removedRefs').val(vals);


    console.log(vals)

    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  },
  selectableOptgroup: true
});
```

I expect when you search for Enemies, options Palpatine and Darth Vader should appear

example of dual transfer list both have search options:
[dual transfer list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5n7X.png)

Current JS used to help with searching: https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

Answer (score 0):

This code first shows all of the options, then hides the optgroup that do not match the search.

```js
let searchstr = "Enemies";

document.querySelectorAll("#searchableb optgroup").forEach(function(e){
    e.style.display = "block";
});

document.querySelectorAll("#searchableb optgroup:not([label*='" + searchstr + "'])").forEach(function(e){
    e.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id="searchableb" name="my-select[]">      
  <optgroup label='Friends'>
    <option value='1'>Yoda</option>
    <option value='2' selected>Obiwan</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label='Enemies'>
    <option value='3'>Palpatine</option>
    <option value='4' disabled>Darth Vader</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: this did not work for the multiselect dual transfer list. It currently uses this script to help with search but it doesn't return the optgroup labels. https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch. I believe the code above would work if it was a dual transfer list. and just a regular multiselect list.

Comment: **  the code would work if it wasn't a dual transfer list. https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch/blob/master/jquery.quicksearch.js - direct link to the js script.